# Numpy "orthogonal" broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

This feels like something for which there should already be a question, but I can't find one.

In numpy, suppose I have two arrays `A` and `B`, how can I ensure that they will be broadcasted "orthogonally" to each other, regardless of the dimensionality of either array? For example I can do this:

```
import numpy as np

A1 = np.zeros((2,2))
A2 = np.zeros((2,2,2))
B = np.ones((2,2))

C1 = A1 + B[...,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
C2 = A2 + B[...,np.newaxis,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]

print(C1.shape)
print(C2.shape)
```

which gives

```
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

as output. But in order to do that I had to know the number of dimensions in at least one of the arrays. Is there a way to do it without knowing either of them? Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape `B` to include trailing singleton dimensions as many as there are dims in `A` -

```
A + B.reshape(B.shape + tuple([1]*A.ndim)) # where A is generic ndarray
```

Some of the [`NumPy ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html) have `outer` method that takes care of all that work. So, for the additions, we could simply use -

```
np.add.outer(B,A)
```

Comment: Hmm cool, thanks. I think I can use this, though it takes a little more inference than I hoped. I guess there is no way around that though. My use-case was that I am supplying arguments to a function, `f(A,B)`, so I don't actually know what it does, and the function can't be modified to do the inference, so we have to shape the arrays correctly up front. Unfortunately the `A` input here isn't a raw array, it is the output of something else, a list of lists of lists (possibly) where the bottom level has the right sort of arrays to broadcast, but they are a bit difficult to dig out.

Comment: @BenFarmer If A isn't an array, simply do : `np.asarray(A).ndim` to get the number of dims and so on. `asarray` simply gets us a view.

Comment: Unfortunately the nested lists aren't necessarily the same length, so can't be viewed as an array. It's ok though, with a little better tracking of the sizes of things then I can use your solution, so I will accept it.

Comment: The point about this being equivalent to "outer" operations is very nice though. And it seems like you can use `np.frompyfunc` to create a custom ufunc that will behave like this, which is pretty cool. E.g. `def f(a,b):
    return a + b;

uf = np.frompyfunc(f,2,1);

C1b = uf.outer(A1,B);
C2b = uf.outer(A2,B);

print(C1b.shape);
print(C2b.shape);`